# How is double から used here?

Tags: particle-から

[image]
[image]

[image]

In the first bubbles the character points out it has been 10 years since the other person came to their guild.

Then in the second bubble the other person says I suppose "Since I was 6-7" but why is double から used?

いるからそうなる  "Because I was it turned like this?

Answer (score 4):

You reverse caused and effect; there are two different “〜から” though they obviously share etymology. One is attached behind noun phrases and means “from” or “since”. That's the first one “６~７歳くらいから” means something like “since the age of about 6 or 7 years old”. It is also used to mean movement away from, as in “東京から行った。”.

The second “〜から” attaches to the conclusive form of an entire sentence and means “because” but it's important to note that it attaches to the end of the sentence it marks as a cause, not in front of it like in English so “６~７歳くらいからいるから” means “Because I've been here since the age of about 6 or 7”.

So the entire sentence idiomatically translates to “I've been here since the age of about 6 or 7, so it'll end up that way eh.”.

In many cases the meaning can change significantly depending on which one one uses. One could also say for instance:

> 6〜7歳くらい**だ**からいる。

The insertion of “〜だ” turns it into a conclusive sentence so now it no longer means “I've been here since the age of about 6 or 7” but “I'm about 6 or 7 years old, so I'm here.”.

It should be noted that this temporal sense of “〜から” as shown here is combined with nonpast stative verbs and means “have been ... since...”. One would not use “いた” for this sense. Many verbs require the te-iru form as they are not stative by themselves, so for instance “朝から起きている” to mean “I've been awake since the morning.”

Comment: The English "from" and "since" have this nuance of "because" as well. E.g. in a mathematical or scientific paper we might read something like: "From the fact that... we conclude..."